# html form input array data not populating in $_GET

Tags: php, html

this is what I get when I do `print_r($_GET);`

```
Array ([categories%5B%5D] => test1)
```

and this is the html form

```
<form method="GET" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="test1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="test2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="test3" />
</form>
```

so when I change the method to POST, the categories array is populated with the checked checkboxes, but when I choose GET, the first checked checkbox is only there, why this happens? and how do I get the data correctly?

Comment: What you describe is not normal behaviour. Possibly you have some URL rewriting going on on the server that you missed out of the question.

Comment: @Quentin Agreed. [I cannot reproduce the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/7ojuopqe/1/).

Answer (score 0):

There is either additional code on page that is throwing this off or you've got something set up incorrectly in the server settings.  Is there additional code you can paste in that we can see?  I pasted that exact code + a submit button onto my server and it works perfectly with $_GET and $_POST

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>


 <form action="" method="POST" >
  <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="test1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="test2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="test3" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?  Did this help?  If so, please mark as answer.  If not, try to add additional information so that we can help you solve the problem.